# Docker send API request from react app to asp.net Web API server

Tags: docker

so I've started learning docker a few weeks ago and now I decided to make a simple ToDo web application that save/display/update/delete to do items.

So far I've created the api and linked it with a mongo db (I should mention that all of this has been containerized) now I've created the web app and testing it without turning it into a container works fine, but when I create an image of my web app it can't find the asp.net server.

I am aware of docker networking, and I've made sure that all of my containers are on the same network.

I've also gone as far as running an ubuntu container on the same network just to ping and request the api, I am successfully getting a response, but when I use the same url I used in the terminal it doesn't work, it says "Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

```
fetch("http://todo_server/api/Todos",{method:"GET"})
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => {
   this.setState({items:data})
 }).catch((e)=>{
   console.log(e)
 })
```

I've also tried

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
  url: "http://todo_server/api/Todos",
  method: 'get',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
})
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({items:data.data})
  });
```

those two codes I used for the requesting the data, the todo_server is the name of my container, I've tested it in the terminal of my ubuntu container and it work, I get a response back but in my APP I don't get any responses.

when I run my app without a container I just replace the todo_server with the IP address of the container and it works.

Comment: Show us how you run your containers, pls

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found out what the problem was.

Since I was the web app was containerized I thought that the request was being sent through the docker network but actually that was not the case, yes the web app is containerized but it is running inside my host browser so when I send a request the request will be sent through The hosts network not dockers network, so All I had to do is change the request url to the server port that has been attached to my host and it works fine now.